# PDOStatement::bindParam() mistura os dados

Tags: php, pdo

Eu Tenho uma classe que faz a inserção dos registros em uma tabela. 
Os dados que vem da requisição eu os transformo em um array e então construo uma instrução SQL semelhante a isso:

```
INSERT INTO web_messages (pk_web_messages, fk_type_messages, name_user, email_user, title_msg, phone_user, cel_user, end_user, compl_user, city_user, state_user, cep_user, msg_user) VALUES (:pk_web_messages, :fk_type_messages, :name_user, :email_user, :title_msg, :phone_user, :cel_user, :end_user, :compl_user, :city_user, :state_user, :cep_user, :msg_user)
```

Os parâmetros passo por pela função bindParam e quando faço o execute executa um monte de dados loucos na tabela: veja o código como eu monto:

```
        foreach ($this->Dados as $field => $defs): // Constrói os parâmetros do comando INSERT
            if (is_array($defs)): // Se $defs é um array então possui valor e tipo do dado
                $value = ((($defs['type'] > FDT_STR) && (isset($defs['value']))) ? $defs['value'] : null); //  pega o valor ou um tipo de arquivo a ser armazenado
                $type = (($value) ? $FIELD_PDO_TYPE[$defs['type']] : PDO::PARAM_NULL); // Se o valor for nulo retorna PDO::PARAM_NULL senão converte para o tipo correto
                $this->Create->bindParam(":{$field}", $value, $type); // Cria o parâmetro no PDO com o nome do campo, valor e tipo
            else:
                $this->Create->bindParam(":{$field}", $defs); // Cria o parâmetro PDO com o Default (PDO::PARAM_STR)
            endif;
        endforeach;
```

o array dados contém:

```
[pk_web_messages] => 0
[fk_type_messages] => 3
[name_user] => Nome do usuario
[email_user] => email@usuario.com
[title_msg] => Mensagem nova com testes da classe
[phone_user] => (11) 3333-4444
[cel_user] => (11) 2222-3333
[end_user] => Rua do usuário, 1111
[compl_user] => apto 10
[city_user] => Cidade do usuário
[state_user] => SP
[cep_user] => 00.000-000
[msg_user] => 
    (
        [value] => Texto a ser inserido no campo Blob.
        [type] => 6
    )
```

veja que type no campo msg_user significa o mapeamento para inserir objetos em em campo BLOB o qual se transforma na constante PDO::PARAM_LOB.
Se eu faço o debug das variáveis do php tudo trabalha corretamente, porém ao fazer o PDOStatement::execute() ele grava um monte de besteiras no banco de dados, ou dá erro de conversão das variáveis, ou erro que trunca o dado para o campo....
O que pode ser isso?

Comment: Precisa mesmo disso `$FIELD_PDO_TYPE`? Já nao está passando o type certo? Podia ser simplesmente `$type = $value ? $defs['type'] : PDO::PARAM_NULL;`

Comment: Eu acho que até aqui dava pra simplificar `$value = isset($defs['value']) ? $defs['value'] : null;`

Comment: Sim repetem em todos os campo o valor da definição do array do campo msg_user. ex: ele tenta passar pros campos o array inteiro então da o seguinte erro: 
Notice: Array to string conversion in ./include/data/Create.class.php on line 135

Comment: $FIELD_PDO_TYPE é uma array que converte os tipos conforme eu utilizo para as costantes do PDO. só utilizo para fins de melhor leitura
No índice type do campo msg_user eu uso uma constante FDT_TEXT que tem o valor 6;

Comment: Rapaz.... troquei bindParam por BindValue e funcionou direitinho....
Problema resolvido... Obrigado... mas mesmo assim vou fazer este teste que enviastes.

Comment: Nem precisa testar o resto, eu passei batido nessa. `bindparam` é pra pegar o resultado de retorno, e não pra enviar. Eu tava prestando atenção em outras coisas e nem reparei. De fato o `bindvalue` é pra colocar o valor dentro da query, `bindparam` é pra pegar o retorno das linhas de resultado. Eu tava procurando as formigas e não vi o elefante passando.

Comment: ok... então binValue nele.... heheheheh... obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Na verdade o ideal seria o @Raphael restaurar a dele, que tava certa. Não entendi pq ele removeu

Comment: @Bacco restaurei, mas eu removi por que deram downvote sem motivo, e eu não quero ajudar quem dá downvote e não diz o motivo.

Comment: @RaphaelCaldas sugeriria não se preocupar com votos, se a resposta é o que o autor precisa, naturalmente atrai positivos. O Alcindo pode marcar sua resposta como aceita, inclusive, assim já fecha a questão com a solução correta.

Comment: @Bacco é por que sou novo aqui, criei a conta ontem só pra ajudar quem precisa e eu faço um post e recebo downvote sem motivo, é meio que chato sabe, mas vou seguir oque você falou, agora só esperar se vou ser escolhido como a resposta correta, obrigado pela força :D

Comment: @RaphaelCaldas aguenta as pontas aí, e não esquente com voto. Dei uma editadinha pra deixar mais clara a resposta. Não precisa, mas se quiser dar uma incrementada nela explicando a diferença das duas coisas, ajuda o pessoal a ver a solução e atrai mais votos (e editando ela sobe pro topo da lista da entrada do site, chamando a atenção também).

Comment: Putz.... Nem vi isto @RaphaelCaldas, desculpe, eu nem sei como que faz esse tal de voto mas vou tentar corrigir agora.... Sua solução me salvou neste caso.... Muito obrigado mesmo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse `bindParam` está errado, o certo seria usar o `bindValue`:

```
$this->bindValue(':campo',$string,PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Explicando qual a diferença entre o `bindParam` e o `bindValue`(dica do @Bacco)

`bindParam`:

```
$sexo = 'masculino';
$s = $dbh->prepare('SELECT nome FROM cadastro WHERE sexo = :sexo');
$s->bindParam(':sexo', $sexo); // usado bindParam para vincular a variável
$sexo = 'feminino';
$s->execute(); // executado como WHERE sexo = 'feminino'
```

`bindValue`:

```
$sexo = 'masculino';
$s = $dbh->prepare('SELECT nome FROM cadastro WHERE sexo = :sexo');
$s->bindValue(':sexo', $sexo); // usado bindValue para vincular o valor da variável
$sexo = 'feminino';
$s->execute(); // executado como WHERE sexo = 'masculino'
```

Explicando:

A `bindParam` recebe a variável por referência e a `bindValue` utiliza a variável apenas como valor.

Exemplos tirados do: http://devblog.drall.com.br/algumas-diferencas-praticas-entre-pdo-bindparam-e-bindvalue/

Comment: Gostaria que o DownVoter me desse um motivo pelo downvote, se possivel

Comment: É este mesmo o problema. Solução perfeita. troquei o `bindParam`, para `bindValue` e voalá... tudo redondinho. Conforme explicado `bindParam` faz referência a uma varável php, sendo assim não adianta ela conter um valor no comando `bindParam`, e sim após o comando popular a variável com o valor a ser enviado ao banco de dados. Isto é útil quando se vai executar várias vezes o mesmo **SQL** com dados diferentes, um exemplo seria repetidos **inserts** em uma tabela mudando os somente o valor das variáveis php, sem necessidade de um novo prepare e novo `bindParam`.

Comment: Novamente me desculpe, pois não sabia deste caso de votação.... agora que compreendi como funciona..... É duro a pressa... kkkkkk Mas muito obrigado pelo teu esclarecimento.